# Append absolute base URL to xPath relative src attribute

Tags: xpath

Is there such a thing as to append the base url to the relative src URL with xPath?
I want to have absolute image URL from the relative one.

E.g.:

To grab the src:
**`<img src="/images/image.jpg" />`**

I used:

**img/@src**

Now I want to make it absolute with appending http://myothersite.com/:

**http://myothersite.com/images/image.jpg**

Any hint would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

UPDATE:
source HTML structure of http://myothersite.com:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="header">
        <h2>Some title</h2>
        <div id="date">8th March 2008</div>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
      <div id="main-content">
        <div class="region">
          <div id="block-system-main">
            <div class="block-content">
                <div id="node-123" class="clearfix">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="body">
                                            <!-- Here I want to grab absolute path, as http://myothersite.com/images/image.jpg -->
                            <p><img src="/images/image.jpg"/></p>
                            <p>Some content ....</p>
                        </div>    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Complete syntax:

Context:

```
//div[@id='main']
```

title:

```
//div[@id='main']/div[1]/h2
```

created:

```
//div[@id='date']
```

body:

```
//div[@id='node-123']/div/div
```

image with error **There was an error with the XPath selector: Invalid expression**:

```
//div[@id='node-123']/div/div/*/concat('http://myothersite.com',img/@src)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for XPATH `concat('http://myothersite.com',img/@src)` function? For example,

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
   <absolutepath>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('http://myothersite.com',img/@src)"/>
   </absolutepath>
  </xsl:template>
```

---

I think you cannot use `concat` like that. Try:

```
concat('http://myothersite.com',//div[@id='node-123']//div[@class='body']/p/img/@src)
```

This gets the first `p/image` body child.

Comment: Yes I think concat is the function. But using the pattern below don't import the image: //div[@id='node-123']/div[2]/div/*/concat('h t t p : / / myothersite.com',img/@src). With no spaces. I have a Feeds importer, where I place all xPath expression in such a manner. Other fields are imported fine, except for those relative path images where I need to append the domain name to make it absolute.

Comment: Do your mean the `href` is not resolved correctly? Can you add to your question a sample of your source document? Can you show your transform as well?

Comment: @swan: i've edited my answer. If you are still in trouble I think I would need to get a look to the transform you are using.

Comment: You are my hero. You save many hours. How can I add 10 points for you? Thanks so much.